# How to make program which will react on button pressing (such as "more" on 'q')

Tags: solaris, c, ncurses, more

I' m trying to realize, how does work pg\more\less utilities. 
For example, cat somebigfile | more. More now in interactive mode. His fd table is:
0 (read pipe from cat)
1 (stdout)
2 (stderr)

I can open /dev/tty on 3 fd and read commands thence. But more can execute some actions without enter pressing. On linux i can use ncurses. What i need to realize to make it on Solaris?

Comment: On Solaris, you can also use curses or ncurses, very much like Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to read() one character from your input; see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/util-linux-ng/trunk/view/head:/text-utils/more.c#L1908 as an example (which I discovered via a Google search result of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854267/implementing-the-more-unix-utility-command):

```
int readch(void)
{
    unsigned char c;

    errno = 0;
    if (read(fileno(stderr), &c, 1) <= 0) {
        if (errno != EINTR)
            end_it(0);
        else
            c = otty.c_cc[VKILL];
    }
    return (c);
}
```

Comment: No, terminal driver doesnt work this way. It sends input to stdin only after <cr>. I can do it this way but i need press enter after that

Comment: See the set_tty function where it sets ICANON ...